# 404 Error: "The requested resource /Controller is not available"

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have setup Spring MVC 3.0 & Hibernate on Apache Tomcat and got the application to launch without any errors.

However I’m available to route requests from my (welcome file) `redirect.jsp` to the home controller (`/Home`).

---

This is what is supposed to happen:

1. Welcome file `redirect.jsp` sends request using `<%response.sendRedirect(/Home)%>`
2. My home controller (`/home`) returns the view `index` which is in `WEB-INF/views`

---

> This is my `web.xml`: I mapped the home controller (`/Home`) via annotation and in`web.xml` however its still not being found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.app.controller.spring.HomeController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

---

This is my `application-context.xml`'s snippet:

```
<!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />-->

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes --> 
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.   For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package--> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.mvc" />    
<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.  Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  --> 
<mvc:annotation-driven />      
<!-- mapping of static resources-->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" /
```

>

---

This is my `app-servlet`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"     
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

However I’m getting a `404` Error,

> The requested resource (`/Home`) is not available.

---

What I would actually like to do is to remove the `redirect.jsp`, have the application go to `\Home` controller on `launch/startup`, and the `\Home` controller returns the index view or any other view.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that in your web.xml, you call your config location `applicationContext.xml`, but you later described it as `application-context.xml`. Make sure it is actually named `applicationContext.xml`. Also, you can remove the "Home" servlet from your web.xml; this will be handled by Spring through your dispatcherServlet. Finally, in your `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, you define the mapping to be `index.html`, but you need to also define `Home` if you want requests to `Home` to be handled by `indexController`. Hope that helps.

Comment: thats just a spelling mistake in the question, the xml clearly states applicationContext.xml

Comment: ok, figured it might be. I was just pointing it out in case it wasn't.